# Extract all dictionary values from JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a JSON which has an entry like following

JSON:

```
"uuid": [
        {
            "id": "c01c0b24-e148-4fa6-87d2-c612173d47c0",
            "reboot": true
        },
        {
            "id": "2f67fe07-b75b-4c3c-b983-eeccc20a6625",
            "reboot": false
        }
    ]
```

I am trying to extract only the 'id''s value like

```
c01c0b24-e148-4fa6-87d2-c612173d47c0
2f67fe07-b75b-4c3c-b983-eeccc20a6625
```

I am trying following statement but I keep getting dictionary errors

```
logger.info("UUID info: {0}".format((api_call).get('uuid')[0]('id')))
```

ERROR:

```
"errorMessage": "'dict' object is not callable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
```

Also what if I have to print all of them, let's say n # of "id' ?

Comment: Change `('id')` to `['id']`

Comment: @Selcuk it worked ! but how would I get all of 'id''s ? . its just giving me the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a proper answer as it's hard to write this in a comment. You should traverse all `dict`s inside the `uuid` list and log them separately:

```
for uuid in api_call.get('uuid'):
    logger.info("UUID info: {0}".format(uuid['id']))
```

or if you prefer to log them in a single line:

```
logger.info("UUID info: {0}".format(
    ", ".join([uuid['id'] for uuid in api_call.get('uuid')])))
```